# Why doesnt my app redirect when I tell it to?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following Actionresult.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Logon(AdminModel model)
{
    if (model.UserName == "x" && model.Password == "x")
    {
        Session["Authenticated"] = "true";

        RedirectToAction("CreateBlog", "BlogController");

    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");

    }

    return View(model);


}
```

However when get to the RedirectToAction call the code carrys on until the View call and then complains that I have no Logon view. But I dont need one im using a 'Index' view to display the logon details and I just want the above to take me to another view. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, return:

```
return RedirectToAction("CreateBlog", "BlogController");
```

In ASP.NET MVC controller actions **return** action results. In your case you are simply calling the `RedirectToAction` method but not returning its result. In your code sample the action executes up until it reaches the last line which of course returns a view instead of redirecting. You definitely want to stop the action execution and redirect immediately by returning the proper action result.

Comment: Ah I see, can I just ask should you always have a view that corresponds to the ActionResult name or is it okay to create actionresults that just throw the user to other views?

Comment: Views should be reusable. But the phrasing "throw the user to other views" sounds like a non-sequitur. The user is *presented with a view* as the result of some actions.